# get_template_directory has an odd functionality

Tags: themes, directory

I have Wordpress 4.4 installed localy on wamp server 2.5 x64 on Windows 10 and noticed that:

```
get_template_directory();
```

returns this:

```
'C:\wamp\www\my-site//content/themes/my-theme'
```

**Questions**

1. What's the reason for those **two** sequential slashes, if this is not a bug?
2. Why Wordpress does not handle **DS** correctly (regarding slashes and backslashes)? is this something up to the web server or the script itself?

Comment: Is the folder called `my-site` or `my-site content`? Sometimes a `//` can represent a space in a file path.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug the `get_template_directory();` should not return a string that looks like that, try making another installation of WordPress, and echo the `get_template_directory();` and see if the output is the same, if it is not then there is something wrong with the first installation.